# CKEditor update notification

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

Want to remove "This CKEditor 4.22.1 version is not secure. Consider upgrading to the latest one, 4.24.0-lts." from appearing in my Django admin's RichTextUploadingField. Currently using Django CKEditor 6.7.0m all settings are in settings.py only. Configs:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
"default": {
"skin": "moono",
"toolbar": "Custom",
"allowedContent": True,
"extraAllowedContent": "object\[id,name,width,height\];",
"extraPlugins": "iframe",
"iframe_attributes": {
"sandbox": "allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-presentation allow-forms",
"allowfullscreen": "",
"loading": "lazy",
"referrerpolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
},
"toolbar_Custom": \[
{
"name": "document",
"items": \[
"Source",
"-",
"Save",
"NewPage",
"Preview",
"Print",
"-",
"Templates",
\],
},
{
"name": "clipboard",
"items": \[
"Cut",
"Copy",
"Paste",
"PasteText",
"PasteFromWord",
"-",
"Undo",
"Redo",
\],
},
{"name": "editing", "items": \["Find", "Replace", "-", "SelectAll"\]},
{
"name": "forms",
"items": \[
"Form",
"Checkbox",
"Radio",
"TextField",
"Textarea",
"Select",
"Button",
"ImageButton",
"HiddenField",
\],
},
"/",
{
"name": "basicstyles",
"items": \[
"Bold",
"Italic",
"Underline",
"Strike",
"Subscript",
"Superscript",
"-",
"RemoveFormat",
\],
},
{
"name": "paragraph",
"items": \[
"NumberedList",
"BulletedList",
"-",
"Outdent",
"Indent",
"-",
"Blockquote",
"CreateDiv",
"-",
"JustifyLeft",
"JustifyCenter",
"JustifyRight",
"JustifyBlock",
"-",
"BidiLtr",
"BidiRtl",
"Language",
\],
},
{"name": "links", "items": \["Link", "Unlink", "Anchor"\]},
{
"name": "insert",
"items": \[
"Image",
"Flash",
"Table",
"HorizontalRule",
"Smiley",
"SpecialChar",
"PageBreak",
"Iframe",
"Embed",
\],
},
"/",
{
"name": "styles",
"items": \["Styles", "Format", "Font", "FontSize"\],
},
{"name": "colors", "items": \["TextColor", "BGColor"\]},
{"name": "tools", "items": \["Maximize", "ShowBlocks"\]},
{
"name": "about",
"items": \[
"About",
\],
},
\],
"language": "en",
}
}
```

Tried to add "ignoreUpdates": True,"updateCheck": False, to config, but no effect. "CKEDITOR_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION = False" gives nothing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently the check of the version of the editor is a new configuration option, described here Class Config (CKEDITOR.config) | CKEditor 4 API docs 2 .

It was added in CKEditor version 4.22.0; XWiki upgraded to CKEditor 4.22.1 in this ticket Loading... 4 .

From what I tested and from what I understand from the ckeditor configuration, the check itself can be disabled by adding:

config.versionCheck = false;

in the CKEditor configuration in XWiki in the administration in the advanced section of the editor configuration: https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/CKEditor%20Integration/#HAdministrationSection 7 .

This will disable the warning because it will prevent the editor from checking its own version, but it will not fix the version of the editor in any way.

Hope this helps,
Anca

https://forum.xwiki.org/t/cke-editor-warning-4-22-1-version-not-secure/14020/4

Comment: After upgrading to Django-ckeditor 5, I had to revert back to ck4 because it is better for me than ck5.

ck4, I can almost fully customize it, including the YouTube plugin where I can chose to show the video or just thumbnail.

I did a lot of personalized configuration on my ck4 and after trying ck5 for over 5 hours, I choose ck4.

Comment: an Ultimate thanks, it's worked.